# How to prevent the output of last comma character in line when writting to file

Tags: c#, file-io, matrix, readfile, chars

Maybe it's a very stupid question (I'm really noob with writing/reading/manipulate files) but I tried different method (found online and here on the site) but nothing worked :/
I have my matrix that is written in a file, and between each element of the matrix, there is a " , " like divider.
I want " , " between every element but not at the end of the rows, so I opened again the file and tried to delete last char from each rows, but my code don't work!

```
//writing on the file
         using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("PATH"))
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < colonne; i++)
             {
                 for (int y = 0; y < righe; y++)
                 {
                     tw.Write(matrice[y, i]+","); 
                 }
                 tw.WriteLine();
             }
         }

         using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("PATH"))
         {
             fs.SetLength(fs.Length - 1);
             fs.Close();
         }
```

Thank you!

Comment: WriteLine is equivalent to `Write("\r\n")`.  So the last three characters are `,\r\n`.  You are removing the `\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about you simply do not output the ',' if last element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < colonne; i++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < righe; y++)
    {
        tw.Write(matrice[y, i]); 

        if (y < righe - 1)
            tw.Write(",");
    }

    tw.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: You could also write the comma before the item: `if (y != 0) { Write(","); } Write(matrice[y,I]);`

Comment: Yeah, I would say that is even nicer

Comment: Before or after is kinda just preference but this is the right answer

Comment: You could also use a ternary statement: `tw.Write(matrice[y, i]+(y < (righe - 1) ? "," : ""));`  Whether that's still "readable" just depends on who you ask.  If you prefer to prepend the comma, then: `tw.Write((y == 0 ? "" : ",") + matrice[y, i]);`